# AWS Lex Fulfillment with Lambda does not work in android when I configure Lex with AWS Mobile Hub, How to fix?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-mobilehub

Hi I'm new in AWS and I'm working with AWS Lex bot, my problem is that I configured Lex bot with Fulfillment through lambda function, it works on Lex test bot successfully but when I configure lex on AWS mobile hub and download android source code and run on android device then all lex intents works but fulfillment lambda function does not response anything.

How can I resolve that
Thanks

Comment: Mashood,

We'll need a little more information to determine what your issue is. Have you tried a simple case first (not using Lambda fulfillment) to make sure the Lex button is working as you expect and responding correctly?

Once you've done that and it is working, if you are still having an issue can you post what your Lex bot setup looks like and your Lambda function?

Regards, Kevin

Comment: @KevinR I test the bot without lambda fulfillment but not for lex button because my bot don't need any button

Comment: So it works when you aren't using the Lambda fulfillment?

Comment: yeah @KevinR it works fine with lambda fulfillment in Lex testing bot but when I connect it with AWS Mobile hub and run on android device Lambda fulfillment doesn't work

Comment: What are you doing when you say you are connecting it with Mobile Hub?  Are you following the Hub steps to integrate it with your app?

Answer (score 0):

The return flow for Lambda fulfillment is a little different in that the Lambda function is responsible for the fulfillment once all the slots are satisfied rather than passing it back to the client to do the fulfillment.  If you'd like to see the message come back you can change promptUserToRespond in ConversationalBotTextFragment.java (mysampleapp/demo/bots/ConversationalBotTextFragment) to the following:

```
    public void promptUserToRespond(Response response,
                                    LexServiceContinuation continuation) {

        if(!DialogState.ReadyForFulfillment.toString().equals(response.getDialogState())
                && !DialogState.Fulfilled.toString().equals(response.getDialogState())) {
            addMessage(new TextMessage(response.getTextResponse(), "rx", getCurrentTimeStamp()));

            readUserText(continuation);
        }
        else if(DialogState.Fulfilled.toString().equals(response.getDialogState())) {
            addMessage(new TextMessage(response.getTextResponse(), "rx", getCurrentTimeStamp()));

            inConversation = false;
        }
    }
```